# Where is the css style sheet for Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I do not seem to have a Vaadin .css in my web-inf directory. Where ias it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default stylesheets are all packaged inside the Vaadin JAR, and are served from there.

If you need a custom theme, then you need to create the folder and theme file yourseld inside the WebContent/VAADIN/themes folder.

(**Edit:** corrected the path, it *shouldn't* be WEB-INF/VAADIN. WebContent/VAADIN/themes is the correct place for custom themes)

Comment: What if you have a Maven project and Vaadin in there, so that now the folder is actually `/webapps/WEB-INF/VAADIN` and not `/WebContent/WEB-INF/VAADIN`? Is the location hard-coded on Vaadin, because this configuration seems not to work with me?

Comment: I am making the theme change for table. Table default seems to be on jar at /VAADIN/themes/base/table/table.css but I don't know where I can put the custom one. Is there any required place?

Comment: I opened question: [How to add css to Vaadin / Maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120436/how-to-add-css-to-vaadin-maven-project)